# C# Excel data export WITHOUT OPENING the Excel doc

Tags: c#, excel, export

I have this very basic application for data export to Excel:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xlsApp.ActiveSheet;
xlsApp.Visible = true;
ws.Cells[1,1] = "First Name";
ws.Cells[1,2] = "Last Name";
ws.Cells[2,1] = "Mary";
ws.Cells[2,2] = "Poppins";
ws.Cells[3,1] = "Grace";
ws.Cells[3,2] = "Kelly";
```

I need to modify it so that the xls file is **not opened** in my pc, but just **created** and **saved**.
How can I?

Thank you!!

Comment: If the reason is because Excel is not installed then you should not use interop, check out the ClosedXML project.

Comment: How would you modify it without opening it? You mean without interop or something else?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, just without showing the opening of the file on my pc.

Comment: What if you set `Visible` to `false` then?

Comment: Great! It works!! The only thing is that if I do Ctrl+Alt+Canc I can still see Excel between the processes. How can I close its execution? @PatrickHofman

Comment: `xlsApp.Close()` or `xlsApp.Exit()`, something like that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman not available methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to set the Property "Visible" of your Excel.Application-Object to false:

```
xlsApp.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Great! It works!! The only thing is that if I do Ctrl+Alt+Canc I can still see Excel between the processes. How can I close its execution? @Kevin H.

Comment: @Elena try `wb.Close()` and then `xlsApp.Quit()`. Interop is a COM library and you should be really careful, otherwise it will stick around. I suggest you using other library to avoid this kind of problems. If you're working with xlsx or xlsm, try EPPlus https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/topics

Comment: Hello @Elena, i hope we could find the solution for your problem. If the solutions solves your problem feel free to set the "question-solved"-mark :-)

Comment: Just checked, it works! Thank you, @KevinH. !! :-)